# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition doesn't render fonts properly

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

So i recently decided to upgrade from the community edition to the ultimate edition, only to run into weird looking fonts

here's how UE looks

[image: Ultimate edition]

[image: UE]

compared to CE
[image: Community Edition][image: CE]

i have no idea what causing this, please how do i fix this? looking at it burns my eye sockets.

Comment: I looked several times at them and could not discern a difference. Did you upload the correct 2 distinct screenshots?

Comment: yes i did, the first one has sort of pixelated fonts.

Comment: I've added another image

Comment: There are a bunch of font rendering settings you can fiddle with. They also have support forums where you might get better help than here.

Comment: You are using the custom third-party theme, also the fonts can be customized in IDE settings.